# How do I make a game object move continuously as long as the key is pressed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am trying to make a game `object` (here, the welcome text) move as long as the `key` is pressed on the keyboard. But in this code of mine,

```
import pygame , sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

WHITE = (255 , 255 , 255)
RED   = (255 , 0 , 0)

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((800 , 400))
pygame.display.set_caption('Welcome Tanks')

#render(text, antialias, color, background=None)
fontObj = pygame.font.SysFont('serif' , 40)
text = fontObj.render('Welcome Folks' , True , RED )

x = 150
y = 29

while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(text ,(x , y))   
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN or event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:               
                y += 15
            elif event.key == K_UP:
                y -= 15
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                x += 14
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                x -= 15
            else:
                x = 150
                y = 29
    pygame.display.update()
```

The object moves only once, even though the `key` is continuously pressed for a long time. In other words, the object changes its position only once when the keyboard button is pressed. I want it to move continuously while I hold the key.

Which event should I look for instead of `event.KEYDOWN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use the `key.get_pressed()`, e.g.

```
while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(text ,(x , y))   
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN or event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)

    if  pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
        x -= 15

    if  pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT]:
        x += 14

    if  pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
        y -= 15

    if  pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
        y += 15
    pygame.display.update()
```

**pygame.key.get_pressed()**

> Returns a sequence of boolean values representing the state of every
>   key on the keyboard. Use the key constant values to index the array. A
>   True value means the that button is pressed.
>
> Getting the list of pushed buttons with this function is not the
>   proper way to handle text entry from the user. You have no way to know
>   the order of keys pressed, and rapidly pushed keys can be completely
>   unnoticed between two calls to pygame.key.get_pressed(). There is also
>   no way to translate these pushed keys into a fully translated
>   character value. See the pygame.KEYDOWN events on the event queue for
>   this functionality.

Also you can take a look at [doc](https://www.pygame.org/docs/)

Comment: Thanks bro !! but could you please explain me the get_pressed() function and also it tells that key variable is not defined .

Comment: try this `from pygame.locals import *`, or `pygame.key.get_pressed()`

Comment: Oh yes !! I understood everything clearly now. Thanks bud !

Comment: You're welcome :) check de documentation, its very clear and usefull

Answer (score 2):

```
 keyState = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

Declare that, and then you use keystate:

```
 if KeyState()[K_DOWN]:
         y += 15
```

You could try:

```
if key.get_pressed()
    down = True

while down = True:
    y+= 15
```

Then get `FPS` clock so it does not just flow over the `screen`!